# Get resource identifier from name

Tags: android

I am developing an application that reads the resource name of each logo from database and then tries to set the drawables.

However, I get a `NumberFormatException` in my Logcat when I try to obtain the integer identifier of the logo and my application suddenly force closes in the beginning of the application.

My code is as follows:

```
String logo;
logo = c.getString(2);
button.setBackgroundResource(Integer.parseInt(logo));
```

`logo` is saved in the database as for example: `R.drawable.logo`

Do you have a suggestion what goes wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the value of `logo` is `"R.drawable.logo"` (a `String`), then that can't be parsed to `int`. R.drawable.logo is actually a reference to the `static int logo` variable in the `static class drawable`, which is a subclass of the generated resources class `R`. `R` is a generated resources class, which you can find in your project under the `gen` folder.

You have to parse it yourself. If you know that it's a drawable that will be returned, you have to do something like:

```
String logoParts [] = logo.split ("\\.");
int logoId = getResources ().getIdentifier (logoParts [logoParts.length - 1], "drawable", "com.example.app");
```

Alternatively, you can separate it into a function:

```
public static int parseResourceString (Stinrg resString, String package) {
    String resParts [] = resString.split ("\\.");
    return getResources ().getIdentifier (resParts [resParts.length - 1], resParts [resParts.length - 2], package);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String logo=c.getString(2);
```

Get your drawable name, no need of R.drawable so removing them by splitting.

```
logo=logo.split("\\.")[2];
```

Third parameter is your package name

```
int drawableId = getResources().getIdentifier(logo, "drawable", "com.mypackage.myapp");

button.setBackgroundResource(drawableId);
```

Comment: thanks, I get a problem in the line logo=logo.split(.)[2];. can you explain about it?

Comment: The problem with the split is because the dot should be provided as a string. Also, since this is a regular expression, it should be escaped as a special character. However, since the backslash is a java escape character as well, that has to be escaped too. It should be "\\.".

Comment: @Shade yeah missed that as I haven't typed it in any java editor